# I cant erase the elements from a vector properly

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, erase

So I am trying to append element from vector b into the end of vector a while erasing all the content in vector b. Below is my code, for some reason that erase is not working properly. Any input is appreciated Thx!!

```
void problem3(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int>& b){
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
    int place_holder;
    for (iter i = b.begin();i !=b.end();i++){
        place_holder = *i;//use place hodler to store values temporairly 
        a.push_back(place_holder);//erase the elements from b
            b.erase(i);
        //std::cout<<b.size()<<'\n';
        //append at the end of a
    }
}
```

Comment: A much better idea would be just to take out `b.erase(i)` from the loop, and then erase all the elements after the loop finishes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a good idea to erase one element in the loop as the vector size is changing dynamically, which you will easily lose the correct index track.

Instead, try to erase all `b`'s elements once in the end:

```
b.clear();
```

---

**P.S.:** There is one easier way to append a vector to another by using  [**`std::vector::insert()`**](http://cppreference.com/wiki/stl/vector/insert) so that all you need is:

```
a.insert( a.end(), b.begin(), b.end() );
b.clear();
```

Comment: +1 dropping my answer. I totally forgot the vector insertion function (shows how often I use it).

Comment: so the insert() takes three arguments?

Comment: @user3444882 It can take two or three arguments. Here, you need to use the one which takes 3 ones.

Answer (score 4):

This is because your iterator becomes invalid on erase. `erase` [will return](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) you the iterator pointing to the next element, e.g. `i = b.erase(i)`. Please be aware, that you want to avoid `i++` (or better: `++i`) in the for-loop, otherwise elements might be skipped.

Comment: Adding to this (to be fully explicit), you need to replace `b.erase(i)` with `i = b.erase(i)`.

Comment: @xcdemon05 if doing that, the loop condition also needs to be adjusted, as you do not want to do `i++` after that